# How to map Delete and End keys on tcsh shell?

Tags: shell, keyboard, tcsh

I use tcsh , and when Delete/End is pressed on cmd line, it simply shows up as `~` ; I have to press `<Ctrl><e>` to go to end of line. Can anyone help me to be able to use Delete/End keys as their name suggests ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those keys already worked on my Debian system.  I found these commands in the `/etc/csh.cshrc` file:

```
if ($?tcsh && $?prompt) then
        bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line # Home
        bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line # Home rxvt
        bindkey "\e[2~" overwrite-mode    # Ins
        bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char       # Delete
        bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line       # End
        bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line       # End rxvt
endif
```

Comment: I found that instead of memorizing the cryptic \e[ sequence , you can directly type:
`bindkey <Ctrl><v><Delete> delete-char` - that way you don't need to hunt for the sequence !! :)

Anyway , your's was the most comprehensive answer !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `bindkey` builtin. See the [tcsh man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tcsh/) discussion for details (search for 'bindkey'), but you want to add a line like

```
bindkey [end] end-of-line
```

to your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` file, replacing '[end]' with the actual <kbd>end</kbd> keypress. See [this page](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/bindings.html#section6) for the list of binding names and helpful examples.

Comment: Correct , but when typing in the above line (I'm using vim), u have to replace [end] with `<Ctrl><v><End>` !!

Answer (score 0):

There's a great resource on fixing inconsistencies with delete/backspace [here](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html).  The document also addresses mapping home/end, though that's not the focus.

Comment: Yes , I got that doc from google , but it was too generalized (not to add huge !!) ... I guess u r more patient than I am !! :)